# how do i validate multiple textbox in dojo?

Tags: dojo

i m using dojo toolkit as design with codeigniter.

I am using dojo dialog as input form for particular module

The problem which i am facing is that, dojo validates only the initial input field and rest fields are not validated in the form.

I am using following function to validate text fields of form :

```
function dialogpartyclose()
{
    if(dijit.byId('txtpartyname').validate() == false)
    {   
        dijit.byId('txtpartyname').validate(true);
    }
    if(dijit.byId('txtpartyfirstname').validate() == false)
    {
       dijit.byId('txtpartyfirstname').validate(true);
    } 
    if(dijit.byId('txtpartylastname').validate() == false)
    {
        dijit.byId('txtpartylastname').validate(true);
    }
    if(dijit.byId('txtpartymobile').validate() == false)
    {
        dijit.byId('txtpartymobile').validate(true);
    }
    if(dijit.byId('txtpartyfax').validate() == false)
    {
        dijit.byId('txtpartyfax').validate(true);
    }
    if(dijit.byId('txtpartyphone').validate() == false)
    {
        dijit.byId('txtpartyphone').validate(true);
    }
    if(dijit.byId('txtpartyemail').validate() == false)
    {
        dijit.byId('txtpartyemail').validate(true);
    }
    if(dijit.byId('txtpartycity').validate() == false)
    {
        dijit.byId('txtpartycity').validate(true);
    }
    if(dijit.byId('txtpartystate').validate() == false)
    {
        dijit.byId('txtpartystate').validate(true);
    }
    if(dijit.byId('txtpartycountry').validate() == false)
    {
        dijit.byId('txtpartycountry').validate(true);
    }
}
```

now if i will click on submit button once,it will validate input fields.
if i close input form and reopen it then all fields are marked red meaning that last validation of fields are not put into its initial stage and last stage of input form is as it is. The problem is that it validates only the first field while reopening form and rest fields are red marked.

Plz helppppppppp

Thnx in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using dijit.form.ValidationTextBox and dijit.form.Form for the input fields and the form.

If so, you do not need the dialogpartyclose() method that seems to be validating all the fields.

Upon submit, dijit.form.Form will invoke the validator function on each of the dijit form fields

For example:

```
<input type="text"
    name="txtpartyname"
    id="txtpartyname"
    dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox"
    required="true"
    constraints="{'constraint1': 'value1'}"
    validator=validateName
    intermediateChanges=false
    invalidMessage="Please enter a valid name. Name must be...." />
```

Then, you can implement your own validator function as:

```
function validateName(value, constraints)
{
    var isValid = false;

    //do the validation here
    if ( <name validation code here>)
    {
       isValid = true;
    }
    //constraints are optional - they get passed into the validator function
    if(constraints && constraints['constraint1'] != null)  {
       //do constraints based processing if required
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

This should take care of proper validations. These validations should only occur when user clicks the submit button
When you close and re-open the dialog, validations will not be run by dijit.form.Form

If you are using a mix of dijit Form input elements and regular HTML input elements you can wire your own validate() function at the form level